# Linux Centos 6: Restart Network Service after lost ping

Tags: linux, networking

My OS is `Linux Centos 6`.  Restart Network Service after lost ping

Basically, I need a watcher or a script that will detect no ping to/from another ip address and run `service network restart`  after every minute or so.

I need to restart the network for various reasons.

Comment: Your link is up and ping fails?

Answer (score 3):

Save this script to file and make it executable. Then run it in a cronjob.

Open your favorite editor and copy this script :

```
#!/bin/bash

# cron script for checking lan connectivity

# Ping count is set aggressively to 1, increase depending what you want.
PING_COUNT=1
#I'm assuming ping is installed.
PING="/bin/ping"


#Find the gateway IP address
GATEWAY_IP=`ip route | grep default | cut -d " " -f 3`
# ping test
$PING -n -c "$PING_COUNT" "$GATEWAY_IP" &>/dev/null

if [ "$?" -ge 1 ]
then
    # This will log a message in system log (see manpage).
    logger "Network access DOWN"

    service network restart
else
    logger "Network access OK"
fi
```

Save the file and name it **checklan** for example.
Make it executable by type in cmdline :

```
chmod +x checklan
```

As root or using sudo, move the file to /usr/local/bin :

```
mv checklan /usr/local/bin
```

Using sudo or root, open a new file in /etc/cron.d

```
vi /etc/cron.d/netcheck
```

Press **i**
Copy the the following line :

```
*/10 * * * * root /usr/local/bin/checklan
```

Save the change by typing **:x**

Restart cron as root or using sudo :

```
service crond restart
```

Then the script should run every 10 mins. 
NOTE: Please read on the Internet about cron to understand syntax.
You can increase rate up to every min.

Check /var/log/messages or /var/log/syslog to see if it is working:

```
tail -f /var/log/messages
```

If it works you will see something like this:

```
Apr  1 20:04:01 <hostname> logger: checklan OK
```

Comment: than kyou, how do I make it executable?

Comment: `chmod +x <name of script>`.

Comment: I did read http://www.linfo.org/create_shell_1.html but still confused..

Comment: This is a newbie user. Do you really want to gice him that trigger happy gun?

Comment: @Nils. If the script was deleting things i could understand your point but this is not the case here. Besides this should not be implemented in prod env without testing. It is provided fas a workaround or for learning purpose.

Comment: I hope he will read this comment. I just imagined what that script would do in a short network outage of a clustered production evironment.

Comment: Where did you configured it to run every 10 Min ?